# how to design an elegant js polling routine?

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I need to poll the database via ajax from js to check for a status.  If the status is "active" then the polling should stop and an alert should popup "case is now active". The js should check the db every 2 seconds until the db status returns "active."  Can you provide an elegant js routine for this?  Here's some general js to show what I want to do:

```
function ReportAsActivePoll()
{
   for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
   { 
      setTimeout(StatusIsActive,(i*2000));
      if(statusIsActive)
      {
         ReportAsActive();
         break;
      }
   }
}

var statusIsActive = false;
function StatusIsActive(case)
{
   statusIsActive = GetStatusFromDB(case) == "active";
}

function ReportAsActive()
{
   alert("case is now active")
}
```

A few notes:

- I know the code above is not correct. It's just for illustrative purposes.
- The code above will call StatusIsActive 10 times. I would like the calls to stop/break/discontinue after status is active. However, I think polling requires to queue up all the calls ahead of time so I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Is getting data from the DB an asynchronous AJAX call in a web browser, or a synchronous call server side in something like node.js? It makes a big difference on how you handle it. If the server knows when the database is updated, it would be even better to make use of sockets so that you don't have to poll for changes at all, and instead send a message to the open connections.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` for simplicity. Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkStatus(theCase) {
    var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (getStatusFromDb(theCase) == 'active') {
            clearInterval(intervalId)
            reportAsActive()
        }
    }, 2000)
}
function reportAsActive()
{
   alert("case is now active")
}

var tmpCounter = 0
function getStatusFromDb(theCase)
{
    if (tmpCounter++ == 4) return "active"
}
checkStatus('case 123')

</script>
```

You should also consider making functions start with a lowercase letter, because that is the normal JS convention. By choosing another style, you risk having case-sensitive errors that are annoying to track down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) instead of your setTimeout and when you received a valid response you have to remove this interval with [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval).

So you need to do something like this

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(function(){
  var resFromYourDB = ...; // get your result via ajax
  if (resFromYourDB['active']){
     window.clearInterval(intervalID);
     // do you alert
  }
}, 2000)
```

This way it will be polling your server till it will get `active` as a response and not a predefined amount of time as with setTimeout. Also when it will get this response it will properely stops.